# New App to AppStore Expedited Review ， how to write the reason?

Tags: app-store

I have developed a new App and want to request a AppStore Expedited Review,but have no idea how to write reason? Can anyone give some help?

Answer (score 0):

Apple provides you already with an answer to that question:

> > ***Urgent Bug Fix*** or ***Time-Sensitive Event***

https://developer.apple.com/support/app-review/ 
https://developer.apple.com/contact/app-store/?topic=expedite

If you just want to speed up the review process, I would not try to get an expedited review.